# selenium no such element error element not found for excel

Tags: excel, selenium

I know this has been asked many times, I apologize for that. but i couldn't solve the problem.
I need to export data from excel to chrome web page. but when I press a button on the web page, the small screen opens and I can't find what I'm looking for there.

to be more specific, this is the page I opened. here I click on the button marked red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEXE7.png)

A screen like this opens. I need to add data here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKpe.png)

my selenium code is like this.

**Public Function kursiyergiris()
Dim tc As Integer
Dim Findby As New Selenium.By
Dim tcekle As Selenium.WebElement
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
Set tcekle = FindElementById("txtTCKimlikNo")     // the part where i got the error
tcekle.SendKeys ("12345678")**

note: when I search, I can see the "txtTCIDID" part.
thank you for the help.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEXE7.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXE4T.png
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKpe.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjnPb.png

Actually "bot.SwitchToNextWindow" is not for the mini window in the 2nd picture. for another window, the login screen. The screen that opens does not have a name. div has name. With the code "Debug.Print bot.IsElementPresent(Findby.ID("RadWindowWrapper_ctl03"))" I can see the div. but I need to write "txtTCIDID" in it.

The 1st photo below is the main screen. The screen where I want to save the second photo. Could you please review it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEXE7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdKpe.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the code bot.SwitchToNextWindow is not switching to the popup window.
Can you replace that code with `bot.SwitchToWindowByTitle "{title of the popup window}"` and see if that works?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Actually "bot.SwitchToNextWindow" is not for the mini window in the 2nd picture. for another window, the login screen.